# Is `join` for a continuation monad always trivial?

Tags: haskell, continuations

Continuations are pretty trivial because `Cont r a ~ a`.

I have worked out `join` to be:

```
join :: Cont r (Cont r a) -> Cont r a
join m = cont $ runCont m (\x -> runCont x)
```

Basically `join` transforms: `(((a -> r) -> r) -> r) -> r` to: `(a -> r) -> r`. So it seems to be that `join` doesn't really do anything at all, but reduce redundancy. Is this correct?

Comment: If you define `join` by `>>= id`, isn't it always trivial?

Comment: @JoshLee if you define `a + b = a - negate b`, isn't it always trivial?

Comment: This would imply `Cont r (Cont r a) = Cont r a`, but e.g. for `Maybe`, we could not say that (because the outer Maybe could be Nothing).

Comment: `Cont r a` is *not* isomorphic to `a`. `foo :: Cont Int a; foo = cont (\_ -> 8)` is a good example.

Comment: Given `newtype Yoneda f a = Yoneda {runYoneda :: forall r. (a -> r) -> f r}`, `Yoneda f` is isomorphic to `f` for any `Functor` `f`. So in particular, `Yoneda Identity a ~= a`. But while `Yoneda` looks an awful lot like `ContT`, that quantified result type makes it behave very differently.